# Life is what you make (of) it

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

Is the preposition **of** necessary in the following?

> Life is what you make (of) it.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: It's optional - but in practice, ***of*** isn't normally included. Besides which it wouldn't scan properly in my favourite Talk Talk track [*Life's What You Make It*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOgzJ8A2QLw)

Answer (score 1):

I think the proposition is not really necessary as without it, the sentence still has the same meaning.

Comment: I would agree. I think the practical meaning is the same. "Life" is simply too vague for there to be a meaningful difference.

Answer (score 1):

Practically speaking the two sentences have the same meaning.

However, there is a subtle difference between the two if you want to be analytical:

> Life is what you make it.

This puts slightly more emphasis on you actively doing something to affect life.

So:

> I decided to make a change by running for government. Now I help serve people every day. I know that life is what you make it.

Here, you go out and change something.

---

> Life is what you make *of* it.

This puts slightly more emphasis on life happening to you, but interpreting it into something significant for you.

So:

> I lost my arm in an accident. It led me to see where I had put my priorities. I see now that life is what you make *of* it.

Here, losing the arm happens to you—and your worldview shifts as you adjust to the new situation.

But, really, the two variations could be swapped, and nobody would be confused.

---

There is also a third variation:

> Life is what you make *out of* it.

I would interpret *out of* in the same way as *of*.

---

Note that there is a different construct, where the pronoun *it* at the end of the sentence is not used. Instead, a different noun follows. In this construct, you have to use a preposition, otherwise the sentence is ungrammatical:

> Breakfast is what I made *out of* eggs.

This is fine. (Even if not a common construction.)

> Breakfast is what I made *of* eggs.

This is also fine; however, I think that the *out of* version sounds more natural in this case.

But:

> ✘ Breakfast is what I made eggs.

Comment: Is it correct to say "I make eggs breakfast every day," meaning "I turn eggs into breakfast every day"?

Comment: @Apollyon No, I would not say that. I would either say *I make eggs* ***for*** *breakfast every day* or *I make* ***an*** *egg breakfast every day*.

Comment: How about "I make life a success"?

Comment: @Apollyon Yes, that works. (You could also say *I make eggs a success*. That's syntactically sound, even if the meaning is opaque.)